# Creating a KM curve function

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to make a KM curve function, however, I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Edit: I have changed the code to see if it will work with the publically available ovarian data set https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/ovarian.html

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot)
library(survival)
library(survminer)



km_curve <- function(df, tm, ev, predictor) {
            surv_object <- Surv(time = df$tm, event = df$ev)
            fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ predictor, data = df)
            ggsurvplot(fit1, data = df, pval = TRUE, xlab = "Months")
            }
```

The above code works perfectly well If I replace all df, tm, ev, and predictor with the actual names.

I also tried this

```
km_curve <- function(df, tm, ev, predictor) {
            surv_object <- Surv(time = df[,tm], event = df[,ev])
            fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ predictor, data = df)
            ggsurvplot(fit1, data = df, pval = TRUE, xlab = "Months")
            }
```

I have also tried

```
   km_curve <- function(df, tm, ev, predictor) {
               tim <- df %>% 
                      select(tm)
               even <- df %>% 
                      select(ev)
               surv_object <- Surv(time = tim, event = even)
               fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ predictor, data = df)
               ggsurvplot(fit1, data = df, pval = TRUE, xlab = "Months")
             }

km_curve(df = ovarian, 
         tm = futime, 
         ev = fustat, 
         predictor = rx)
```

It keeps giving me error messages that pf_time_months not found. Even though it is a column in my data frame I specify.

This does not work either

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
ovarian
km_graph<-function(t, e, var, df, xaxis = "Months"){
  surv_object <- Surv(time = t, event =e)
  fit1<- survfit(surv_object ~ var, data = df)

  kmgraph<-ggsurvplot(fit1, data = df, pval = TRUE, xaxis = "Months", risk.table = T)
  kmgraph$table <- ggrisktable(fit1,
                               data = df,
                               color = "strata",
                               y.text = T,   ylab = "",  xlab = "",
                               tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
      )
       return(kmgraph)
    }

    km_graph(t = ovarian$futime, e =ovarian$fustat, var = rx, df = ovarian)
```

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :
cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show how you are calling these functions and how you are passing in parameters. You can't pass variables to formulas because they are un-evaluated. That's likely the problem but hard to tell without the reproducible example. Also you need to be careful when passing symbol vs values. List all non-base R packages you are using

Comment: The use of `select` a couple of times in your code does not wholly justify the [tag:dplyr] tag much less the [tag:tidyverse] tag (which is far abused, it should not be used just because you use `library(tidyverse)` in a script).

Comment: Sorry about not adding a reproducible example. I have formatted this example to work with the publically available "ovarian" dataset

Answer (score 0):

My guess (I have to guess since you don't provide a reproducible code) is that `pfs_time_months` and others are the names of some columns of `df`. That's why that does not work. You can pass them as character strings if you use this function:

```r
km_curve <- function(df, tm, ev, predictor) {
  surv_object <- Surv(time = df[, tm], event = df[, ev])
  f <- as.formula(sprintf("surv_object ~ %s", predictor))
  fit1 <- survfit(f, data = df)
  ggsurvplot(fit1, data = df, pval = TRUE, xlab = "Months")
}

km_curve(df = first_primaries, 
         tm = "pfs_time_months", 
         ev = "pfs_fail.x", 
         predictor = "risk"
)
```

Comment: That does not see to work either. It is giving me the error message "Error in x$formula : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable" I tried the following.    km_curve(df = ovarian,       tm = "futime", ev = "fustat", predictor = "rx")